# Hidden on topic page

Tags: bug, user-interface

Our FAQ is gone, there is a new [help page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) now. Somewhere, hidden between 27 other links is a link named [What topics can I ask about here?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

No one will ever read this.

We cannot edit the main help page to include this section there.

We can edit the [about page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/about), but the link to that page is hidden at the bottom of each page. And worse: all the text there is centered; and adding text there removes all styles, including list bullets.

I took away at least the misleading announcement we would answer *every WordPress question,* and I added a link to our scope page.

Please fix this bug! The two most common errors for beginners on our site are:

- asking for a plugin recommendation
- asking for WordPress.com support

And now we cannot even say: Please read our FAQ, there you can find what is on topic and what is not. Because there is no short, readable FAQ anymore, just an unreasonable gigantic wall of text and links.

Please do not **hide** essential information. Make it easy to find instead, not more than **one click** from the start page away.

Addendum, see Chip’s answer: And when you are on it, fix all the links created with shortcuts `[faq]` too.

Looks like other SE sites have the same problem:
[Why does Server Fault's new help system de-emphasize the professional audience?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186838/why-does-server-faults-new-help-system-de-emphasize-the-professional-audience)

Comment: Agreed. Finding certain very relevant parts of the FAQ has become difficult. This is a very dysfunctional design change.

Answer (score 6):

Why on earth is it helpful for the "above the fold" content on the **WPSE** help page to be generic information about *SE network sites* in general? All of that *Take the Tour* and *Here's how it works* banner content should be moved to the **About** page.

I assume this also breaks our "magic links" to the FAQ and FAQ sections? So we need some new magic links.

Comment: Yes, links are broken too: `[faq]` = [faq].

Comment: @toscho: The magical [faq] links [now point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183131/1438) to the equivalent page in the help-center/about page for the most part. Of course, that doesn't the core issue, which is that it's difficult to find the bits of the old FAQ that are most important to defining the scope of the site.

Comment: @JonEricson The current target for `[faq]` is the opposite of a FAQ. It is some kind of a … tutorial, not a short list of common issues. I don’t see that as a solution.

Comment: I had no idea we even had magical links, their documentation is so buried. Just gonna leave [these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) [links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) here for anyone else who had a similar reaction.

Answer (score 5):

Asking and Answering are pivotal features of stack,  they are also the most confusing to new users, cluttering the screen with other information creates noise, please consider separating the concerns.