# Site Name: The Final Chapter

Tags: discussion

**UPDATE:  The new name is live in the header image!!   It'll be updated in various text sections shortly. Original post follows.**

Let's be honest, Empire was awesome, but the middle part of a Trilogy is often the weakest. (I'm talking to you, Oceans 12, and Temple of Doom.)

And the community **hated** my [part two](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/site-name-the-unfortunate-sequel) in the site renaming discussion.

I still have some reservations that "Wordpress Development" won't make the scope of the site totally clear, but the truth is that no title will.

And it is a lot clearer than the current one, and I've failed to provide a better alternative.  More importantly, it's what the community thinks fits best.

### So, we're re-reversing our position out of respect for the community's views.

### We will  change the main site header to "Wordpress Development."

And we'll count on you to make the site welcoming to new users who can contribute, including the minority who may not *think of themselves* as "developers," but *are* dealing with legimate, WordPress-specific code problems as they build out their websites.

**Caveat: Design changes (which this is) are a significant bottleneck at the moment, so the actual change will likely take some time.**

### One last question:

We *may* try to include a subtitle, although there are some design constraints that could kill that.  *If* we do, does the following look good, and if not, how would you adjust it?

---

## WordPress Development

**Q&A on Wordpress.org site administration, development, and best practices.**

Comment: Any progress? Please?

Comment: @toscho, we haven't forgotten this.  We've had a massive design backlog.   You're seeing site designs roll out now (Money SE, etc.) that have been in queue for over a year. But we're plowing through MUCH faster now - we have 3 new designers on board (up from 1) in the last two months. I can't say for sure how long it'll be, but my best guess would be more than a week or two, but well before summer.

Comment: @toscho, we did a little better than I'd thought - new name is live in the header!   We'll be updating the text in various places over the next few days.

Comment: @Jaydles The spacing between the words is a little to large. Makes the logo look a little weird on the main site especially...

Answer (score 17):

First - YAY! I know that site naming has always been sensitive issue for higher powers and I am **very** glad community managed to communicate and convince you of our strong stance on the name. Hopefully no hard feelings on some rowdy worded points in the process. :)

Notes on tag line:

- I can't remember on top of my head are there any stacks with tag line already? as in - is there some prior art or we are charting new idea with it here?
- I would put development before administration and drop best practices from it (some of best practices questions are fine, but some are way too meh and let's not enable them)
- I am not sure on WordPress.org, it's understood by anyone who has been around a bit, but usually confuses newbs

So my loose edit would be:

> Q&A on self-hosted WordPress development and administration

Comment: 1. thx for the typo catch on the "P" - fixed it and edited it out of your answer.  2. Yeah, some of the responses were less than charitable, but I know it comes from passion for the site, so no hard feelings at all- when I'm wrong, I'm wrong! 3. Is "self-hosted" accurate?  That sounds to *me* like someone building a site that they have hosted by blue host or someone is in the wrong place, which I assume not to be the case?

Comment: @Jaydles "self-hosted" is accurate. That is the standard way to distinguish between a site hosted on worpress.com and a site hosted (anywhere else) using software downloaded from wordpress.org.

I agree with all of Rarst's suggestions.

Comment: @Jaydles Yes, terminologically "self-hosted" describes it accurately (even when hosting is third party, which it almost always is), as opposed to "hosted" wordpress com version.

Comment: I wouldn't use the term "self-hosted". I think "Q&A on Wordpress development and administration" is sufficient.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you didn't do a good job in between *Part 1* and *The Sequel*, but I just want to acknowledge (and thank you for) all the time you spent on this. Time spent discussing (internal and here on Meta), time spent examining what is, why that is not what the site needs, what might be better, what might be worse in turn.

And last but not least: Thank you for *giving in* to (or to be more precise: believing in and trusting) the Community.

It is the right thing to do—but it still should be acknowledged.

Comment: Thanks - your note means a lot to me. We all want the same thing for the site, but sometimes it takes us a while to figure out the best way to get there (even when some folks like you knew all along...  :) )

Answer (score 7):

I personally liked one of the suggested titles that encompassed the entire scope of the site:

> WordPress Development and Administration

It may be a bit longer than most site titles, but it does not stand alone - there are plenty of other sites in the SE network which use longer titles to convey the exact scope of the site.

A title like this would remove the need for a long and somewhat unnecessary tagline - it conveys the site's scope in the fewest words needed.

If there was some trouble fitting a long title like this in the design, an option might be to have **WordPress Development** on top, big and bold, with **and Administration** underneath in a smaller font.

Answer (score 5):

Pragmatic tag-lines are overrated!

> ## WordPress Development
>
> #### *Just another Stack Exchange community*

<sub><sup>(probably shouldn't actually do this)</sup></sub>

Comment: I love this, but I agree.

Answer (score 3):

All I can think of is this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be ideal, although possibly not practical, for a potential tagline to include *theme and plugin* development, since they are within WPSE scope, and comprise a significant amount of site activity. So I'll throw this out there, and welcome wordsmithing to improve it:

### Q&A on self-hosted WordPress, Theme, and Plugin development and administration

Comment: I agree with your premise, but some wordsmithery may indeed be required - I feel like in its current state, the suggested tagline implies that we also cover theme and plugin administration, which I'm not so certain is the case.

Comment: But then, what is "administration" in this context? If "administration" of WordPress core is within WPSE scope, then one could argue that "administration" of Plugins/Themes installed on self-hosted WordPress is also within WPSE scope.

Comment: **Q&A on Administering and Extending WordPress**, perhaps?

Comment: I somewhat think that "Wordpress Developers" , or "wordpress(for)developers" - as a title would convey better also for the tagline than "Development" - which might be a bit confusing for people who might think it is for core developers . Same for the tagline -  "Extensions Development and Administration for self hosted WordPress" . But since I am not an English native - I might be all wrong here ..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for asking so bluntly ... but what's the current status here?
On New Year's Eve you wrote that *the actual change will likely take some time*. That's alright, but how much is this *some* time?

[This question as well as its comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136248) is the youngest proof of how *urgent* the name change is, or how *misleading* the current one is.

Comment: See response above.  TL;DR - we're backed up on design, but have a ton of new help.  Probably more than a few weeks, but less than a few months.  http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3745/site-name-the-final-chapter/3821?noredirect=1#comment4391_3745

Answer (score -4):

Disagree with this, as per this topic:

[Plugin recommendations are NOT offtopic](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3826/plugin-recommendations-are-not-offtopic)

This Exchange should be renamed Wordpress Codex, as questions whose subject cannot be answered without referencing the Codex are not allowed in this exchange.

The term "development" as used on here has a terribly narrow scope and is ***very*** misleading.