# SE network ads still use the old site name

Tags: bug, promotion

After [Site Name: The Final Chapter](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3745) it would appear that that name "WordPress Answers" is dead, but it survives in the cross-site promotion ads that SE shows in the sidebar. I saw this one just now, on Mathematics.

[image: ad]

Comment: Oh yeah, we need to update the background image for those. I'll work with Jin to get this fixed up and deployed. Thanks for the report!