# Old newsletter design

Tags: discussion, bug

I just got our [newsletter](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters) and discovered that it still has the old design and the even older name, besides the new name in the subject:

> **Subject:** WordPress Development Weekly Newsletter - Thursday, January
>   14, 2016

[image: WordPress Development Weekly Newsletter]

I totally understand that this might be out of scope for [the new design](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4092/32946), but we also had [a similar ticket for the community ads](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3923/32946), so I just wanted to report it, too.